# When do we use in_place=True for BatchNorm layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

The benefit using `in_place=True` for a layer is for saving memory. However, I found some paper like ResNet that use `in_place=False` for the BatchNorm layer. My question is when do we use `in_place=True/False` for the BatchNorm layer. Does it has any effect on performance? Thanks all

```
layer {
  name: "bnorm1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "conv1_bn"
  top: "conv1_bn"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: false
  }
}
```

The related code to make above prototxt is

```
n.bnorm1 = L.BatchNorm(n.conv1_bn, batch_norm_param=dict(use_global_stats=False), in_place=True)
n.scale1 = L.Scale(n.bnorm1, in_place=True, bias_term=True,filler=dict(value=1), bias_filler=dict(value=0))
```

Comment: Are you sure about `resnet`? I saw https://github.com/KaimingHe/deep-residual-networks/blob/master/prototxt/ResNet-50-deploy.prototxt . `in_place` is `True` here.

Comment: Yes. they use in_place is true as your link and in_place is false for https://gist.github.com/ducha-aiki/6457bbd49fea8b7634a7#file-cifar10_full_sigmoid_train_test_bn-prototxt-L73-L114